# How to write TIMESTEMPDIFF QUERY in model codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, timestamp

In MYSQL phpmyadmin i can run this query :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF (MONTH, periodmulai, periodselesai)
FROM tb_projek
```

but how do I write that query in Model codeignitor way? That doesn't work

```
public function get_bulan()
{
$this->db->SELECT_TIMESTAMPDIFF('MONTH,tb_projek.periodmulai,tb_projek.periodselesai');
$this->db->from('tb_projek');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: You better use sql->query() using normal SQL strings. There is absolutely no benefit using the CI active record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this,

```
$this->db->select('TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,periodmulai,periodselesai )',FALSE);
$this->db->from('tb_projek');
```

If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

Comment: ERORR  Brother.. :(
>> Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`tb_projek`)' at line 2

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, `periodmulai`, `periodselesai)` FROM (`tb_projek`)